# Multivariate Cointegration Test?

Tags: r, panel-data, plm

I am currently performing an analysis on FDI and income inequality in a panel of 10 countries over 30 years. In this setting, I want to test for panel cointegration, unit roots etc. My data is currently in the format:

```
ID year var1 var2
1   1    3    4
1   2    4    NA
1   3    1    6
2   1    4    2
2   2    1    3
2   3    2    2`
```

and so on. I have used

```
data.frame(split(df$var1, df$ID))
```

to create a dataframe with the IDs as columns to use the `purtest` function from the `plm` package (note that my panel data is unbalanced). However, I have a lot of variables and this whole procedure seems excessively tedious.

Is there a way to perform a cointegration test on multiple variables at once? There appears to be an `index` specification in `purtest` but I don't fully understand how to use it. What format would my data have to be in and how would I get there? Would it be an issue that there is quite a few NAs in some variables?

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2), 
                 year = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
                 var1 = c(3,5,6,2,NA,6,4, 2,3,4,5,8,NA,7), 
                 var2 = c(5,6,3,8,NA,NA,2, NA,6,7,4,5,9,2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `index` argument to `plm`'s `purtest` works like in the other functions of the package: it is used to specify the individual and the time dimension of your data. However, there is no need to use it directly in the `purtest` (or other functions) if data is converted to a `pdata.frame` first.

There is no need to split the data by individual on your end. `purtest` supports various ways/formats to input data. A user-driven split is just one option. If you already have a data frame in long-format, I suggest to convert it to pdata.frame and input a pseries to purtest (thus, no need to split data yourself). Something along these lines:

```
library(plm)
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2), 
                 year = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
                 var1 = c(3,5,6,2,NA,6,4,2,3,4,5,8,NA,7), 
                 var2 = c(5,6,3,8,NA,NA,2,NA,6,7,4,5,9,2))
pdf <- pdata.frame(df)
purtest(pdf$var1, test = "hadri", exo = "intercept")
```

To test multiple variables at once, you can put the `purtest` function into a loop, e.g., like this:

```
myvars <- as.list(pdf[ , -c(1:2)], keep.attributes = TRUE)
lapply(myvars, function(x) purtest(x, test = "ips", exo = "intercept", pmax = 1L))
```